# Classification using Approximate Nearest Neighbors in Scikit-Learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, nearest-neighbor

I have a labeled dataset having a 46D featureset and around 5000 samples that I want to classify using Approximate Nearest Neighbors.

Since I'm familiar with Scikit-Learn, I want to utilize it to achieve this goal.

The scikit documentations lists LSHForest as one of the probable methods for ANN, but it's unclear to me how to apply that for classification purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very nice question. Unfortunately scikit-learn does not seem to support custom neighbor model now, you can, however implement simple wrapper on your own, such as

```
from sklearn.neighbors import LSHForest
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode

class LSH_KNN:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.n_neighbors = kwargs['n_neighbors']
        self.lsh = LSHForest(**kwargs)

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.y = y
        self.lsh.fit(X)

    def predict(self, X):
        _, indices = self.lsh.kneighbors(X, n_neighbors = self.n_neighbors)
        votes, _ = mode(self.y[indices], axis=1)
        return votes.flatten()
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will surely check this out.

Can you please also tell me, whether there is any way to integrate the approximate neighbor finding mechanism of the [FLANN](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/).
My main query is, I have all these ANN libraries at my disposal, which calculate distances and indexes, how can I utilize them for classification purposes in sklearn?

Comment: you will have to write your own wrappers, like for anything

Comment: Thanks for your input. This was really helpful :)